# How can i keep this table in the shown order?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Hello i have got a table, that uses string indexes:

```
    shirt = {
        ["shirtwhite.png"] = "shirt_white.png",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#3f3f3f"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#3f3f3f",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#ff0000"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#ff0000",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#ff7f00"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#ff7f00",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#ffff00"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#ffff00",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#00ff00"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#00ff00",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#0000ff"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#0000ff",
        ["shirtwhite.png^[multiply:#9f00ff"] = "shirt_white.png^[multiply:#9f00ff",
    },
```

Theese are t-shirt-textures for an editable game-character-skin (with colour-values for different colors).

There are some more of theese tables in the code, for other parts of the character-skin

how can I keep the table in it´s shown order, while it´s loaded in this code-snippet?
The tzables are in a file "skins.lua" and the code-snippet is from another lua-file

```
character_creator = {}
character_creator.skins = dofile(minetest.get_modpath("character_creator") .. "/skins.lua")

local skins = character_creator.skins
local skins_array = {}

minetest.after(0, function()
    local function associative_to_array(associative)
        local array = {}
        for key in pairs(associative) do
            table.insert(array, key)
        end
        return array
    end

    skins_array = {
        skin  = associative_to_array(skins.skin),
        hair  = associative_to_array(skins.hair),
        eyes  = associative_to_array(skins.eyes),
        shirt = associative_to_array(skins.shirt),
        pants = associative_to_array(skins.pants),
    }
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Lua only arrays (positive integer-indexed tables) have "order" (can be iterated using `ipairs`); the hash tables (like the one you are working with) are unordered. If you want to iterate over a table like this in a specific order, you'd usually create an array with the keys, sorted them in the order you want and then iterate over that array extracting elements from your table.

There are also components (like [ordered table](https://gist.github.com/RyanPattison/0f7307ee39a5238270a0)) that may keep track of insertions and return results in the same order, if that's what you want.

Comment: now i created such arrays, wich have numbers as index and the indexes of the original tables as the content. Now i´m looking for a way, how i could use them to access the original tables.

Comment: Look into __pairs metamethod, Ive hooked it and __newindex to retain order for string keys.