# how to make lua table key in order

Tags: json, lua

my test code:

```lua
local jsonc = require "jsonc"

local x = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = 5,
}

for k, v in pairs(x) do
    print(k,v)
end

print(jsonc.stringify(x))
```

output:

```
a   1
c   3
b   2
e   5
d   4
{"a":1,"c":3,"b":2,"e":5,"d":4}
```

#### someone help:

1. from for pairs output, lua store table by key hash order, how can i change it?
2. i need output:  `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`
3. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i keep this table in the shown order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507267/how-can-i-keep-this-table-in-the-shown-order)

Answer (score 0):

Lua tables can't preserve the order of their keys. There are two possible solutions.

You can store the keys in a separate array and iterate through that whenever you need to iterate through the table:

```
local keys = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Or, instead of a hash table, you can use an array of pairs:

```
local x = {
    {'a', 1},
    {'b', 2},
    {'c', 3},
    {'d', 4},
    {'e', 5},
}
```